# ltablex caused the content to exceed the bottom margin of the page

Tags: xetex, tabularx, ltablex

For some reasons, I need to use `tabularx` to typeset tables, and I need to be able to cross pages. So I choose `ltablex` to meet these demands at the same time. However, I found that the content near `tabularx` environment exceeded the lower boundary due to the use of `ltablex`. How can I solve this problem? Is it a bug inherent in `ltablex`? Or if I want a cross-page table to support X columns at the same time, is there any other solution?

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,footskip=0cm,headsep=0cm,headheight=0cm,showframe,showcrop]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=17cm,width=10cm]{fig}
\caption{A}
\end{figure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\begin{table}
\caption{A}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
A & A\\
A & A\\
A & A\\
A & A\\
A & A\\
A & A\\
A & A\\
A & A\\
A & A\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the [`xltabular`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular?lang=de) package, which combines the features of `longtable` and `tabularx`. The very nice allround package [`tabularray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) also supports `X` columns in the `longtblr` environment.

Comment: you have placed it in a `table` so preventing page breaking,

Answer (score 1):

Considering @DavidCalisle and partly @marv comments, your document example can be written as:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm, 
            showframe,showcrop]{geometry}
%\usepackage{tabularx}  it loaded by ltablex
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.8}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=16cm,width=10cm]{example-image-duck}
\caption{My lovely mr. Duck}
    \end{figure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
\caption{Long table using \texttt{ltablex} package}\\
    \hline
\textbf{header 1}
    &   \textbf{header 2}   \\
A   & \lipsum[66] \\
B   & \lipsum[66] \\
C   & \lipsum[66] \\
D   & \lipsum[66] \\
E   & \lipsum[66] \\
F   & \lipsum[66] \\
G   & \lipsum[66] \\
H   & \lipsum[66] \\
I   & \lipsum[66] \\
J   & \lipsum[66] \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Long table set using \texttt{longtvlr} environment defined in \texttt{tabularray} package},
  label = {tab:longtable}
                    ]{
        colspec = {c X[j]},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        rowhead = 1}
    \toprule
header 1
    &   header 2  \\
    \midrule
A   & \lipsum[66] \\
B   & \lipsum[66] \\
C   & \lipsum[66] \\
D   & \lipsum[66] \\
E   & \lipsum[66] \\
F   & \lipsum[66] \\
G   & \lipsum[66] \\
H   & \lipsum[66] \\
I   & \lipsum[66] \\
J   & \lipsum[66] \\
L   & \lipsum[66] \\
L   & \lipsum[66] \\
M   & \lipsum[66] \\
N   & \lipsum[66] \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]